# Inequality on embedding between spaces

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

let $\Omega$ be an open set. We are known that $L^2(\Omega) \hookrightarrow H^{-1}(\Omega)$, so for all $f \in L^2(\Omega)$, we have $\|f\|_{H^{-1}} \lesssim \|f\|_{L^2}$. If we assume $f$ is integrable, we also have the Poincare inequality : $\|\int_{\Omega} f\|_{L^2} \lesssim \|f\|_{L^2} $.

Do we have the following inequality in general ?

$\|f\|_{H^{-1}} \lesssim \|\int_{\Omega} f\|_{L^2}$

Answer (score 1):

No, obviously not. Take any $f \ne 0$ with mean value $0$.